# Counting gas for a contract function execution - growing storage mapping structs

Tags: solidity, gas

I want to `count` (`not estimate` for that I would use web3 API) gas per contract function execution - suppose there is a contract with two `mapping` structs where one is nested in the other. Something like:

```
contract ABC {
    struct Obj {
        // ...
        mapping(string => NestedObj) nestedObjects;
    }

    struct NestedObj;

    mapping(address => Obj) objects;
    
    // ... a few functions adding or modifying the above ^
}
```

No loops, just `adding` or `modifying` of those structs.

I have three questions:

1. if those `structs` mappings grow to arbitrary size in the `storage`, how does that affect gas price when only thing we do is adding or modifying those structs?
2. are there any limitations in size of those Obj/NestedObj in the `storage`?
3. I want to count the gas line by line in my code for all kinds operations, I get there are some EVM codes with assigned gas in the yellow paper but how do they relate to the actual Solidity lang operations? Tried to search the docs/stackexchange/etc. but could not find anything, isn't there some cheatsheet for that?

Any relevant links would be appreciated, thank you!